ESP32 and Motors same supply
I'm working on a Sumo Robot project that uses an ESP32 and 4 DC motors and plan to use a 6 AA battery holder to power the entire thing.
At first I thought I'd need a voltage regulator to feed into the ESP32, but from what I've seen the microcontroller contains its own regulator so in theory I could feed the VIN pin directly from the AA battery holder, which I'd also be connecting to a L298N for the motors. However, I've heard that this can cause problems when the motors start working as the current they need increases greatly in this moment and the noise they produce also causes problems.
What should I do to try to avoid these issues? Should I implement an LDO to try an attempt to protect my circuit, some capacitors between GND and VCC. I've also seen some designs that implement a diode to avoid frying the board in case of a swapped connection, but I'm not sure where I'd put that.
I'm pretty new to working with batteries in these applications and would like to avoid frying my ESP32, so I'd appreciate the help.

Can you use SMD motor driver ICs or a ready made module or is a through hole IC required? Do yourself a favor and use something else than L298, the power losses are enourmous.

When connecting motors and other electronics on the same batteries (especially some with high internal resistance, such a most AA batteries), you have 2 main types of issues :

noise : the voltage is not stable. This can be improved by adding capacitors next to the motor drivers and/or next to your sensitive electronics (ideally, a big electrolytic capacitor to store lots of energy + a ceramic capacitor to handle the high frequency noise). More sophisticated filters are also possible. A linear regulator (LDO or normal) is usually quite good at rejecting noise, and is therefore a nice addition if you mainly care about noise (but not much about efficiency)
voltage drop : whenever you draw too much instantaneous current (mainly big acceleration or starting the motors), the voltage of the battery will drop. If it drops bellow the minimum voltage of the ESP32, it will malfunction (often in form of a reboot). A LDO will not enable you to get more voltage on the output than on the input. A low pass filter can help. Or a buck-boost regulator (that can also provide output voltage greater than input voltage).

Do you already have your circuit built? If so, do you have an oscilloscope to check the voltage drops?
In your place, I would start with a circuit like the following :

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
D1 is if you want reverse battery protection. But you loose at least 0.4V (or more, depending on the diode you use). So you might decide to take the risk to remove it (just make sure not to put the batteries the wrong way).
D2 and C1 are the crucial part : C1 is a big capacitor, that will store energy for the ESP32 during the voltage drops (how bit it needs to be depends on the duration of the voltage drops, and the consumption of the ESP32 ; the bigger the better), and D2 guarantee that C1 will charge when the battery voltage is higher, but is not discharged by the motors when the battery voltage drops.
U2 and C2 are optional : add them if you think you have too much noise (or the input voltage is too high for the internal regulator of the ESP32).
Note on the L298N : I strongly advice you use a different motor controller (or go up to at least 24V batteries). The LN298 is a very old (and inefficient) motor controller, which will cause a voltage drop between 1.8 and 3.2V at 1A, and up to 4.9V @ 2A. So if used with a 6V supply, you might end up loosing more than half your voltage in your controller. For a sumo robot, this means having far less torque, so not being able to push the adversary robot efficiently.

The biggest problem will likely be voltage sag when the motors are running, depending on how big your motors are. AA batteries have a relatively high internal resistance. Your question is too vague to give you a specific solution.
It will be hard to determine if you're having motor noise problems without an oscilloscope. You can probably borrow one if you ask around. They're pretty cheap these days, about 300 USD for a basic one.
If you do have motor noise issues, the first and simplest mitigation is to add ceramic, and large electrolytic caps near the motor drivers and MCU.
What you need to do before you do anything else is create a schematic for your circuit. Don't worry about noise or anything like that just yet. Get the core parts of the design down and connected. Motors, drivers, MCU, etc. Make sure you've got part numbers and datasheets for everything.
Once you've done that, you can either build it, and start troubleshooting, or you can read through the datasheets and analyze the circuit, looking for problems and solutions.
